# What is Super Object in CodeIgniter?

Tags: oop, codeigniter

I saw the term "Super Object" in [CodeIgniter manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html), but the term is not explained in details.

So, what is exactly "super object" in CodeIgnter?

Answer (score 10):

The codeigniter super object is the object that lets you refrence any loaded codeigniter resource or load new ones without initializing the classes each time.

for instance in your library if you wanted to refrence the database you would do the following

```
function whatever()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance()  // sets an object in your library to point to the codeigniter object
    $this->ci->db->get('mytable');
}
```

where in a controller it would just be

```
function whatever
{
    $this->db->get('mytable);
}
```

this is because libraries do not have a refrence to the codeigniter object by default (for many reasons)

Comment: What's the class type of the "super-object"?
Since Controller can directly use $this, it looks like Super-Object is an instance of Controller.(I hope it is not)

Comment: To answer your question, it is indeed an instance of the current Controller that is serving the request.