# Why might variables in a class be required to be static?

Tags: php, class, oop, static

I am attempting to adapt the Amazon Simple Pay Standard PHP library for dynamic use.  It was written to be a button factory of sorts.  The primary section of code that I have found need to edit is the first class, in which are declared many variables.  However, as you can see, they are all `static`:

```
class StandardButtonSample {

    private static $accessKey = "randomKey";
    private static $secretKey = "randomKey";
    private static $amount="USD 10";
    private static $signatureMethod="HmacSHA256";
    private static $description="Test Widget";
    private static $referenceId="test-reference123";
    private static $abandonUrl="http://oust.cc/cancel.html";
    private static $returnUrl="http://oust.cc/return.html";
    private static $immediateReturn="0";
    private static $processImmediate="1";
    private static $ipnUrl="";
    private static $collectShippingAddress=null;
    private static $environment="sandbox";

    public function Sampleform() {
        try{
            ButtonGenerator::GenerateForm(self::$accessKey,self::$secretKey,self::$amount,
          self::$description, self::$referenceId, self::$immediateReturn,self::$returnUrl,
          self::$abandonUrl, self::$processImmediate, self::$ipnUrl,
          self::$collectShippingAddress,self::$signatureMethod, self::$environment);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo 'Exception : ', $e->getMessage(),"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

In trying to modify this, I learned very quickly that I could not simply throw an outside variable into the class, ala `$referenceId = $uid . time();`  However, I found a couple workarounds for that here on SO.  But attempting to use them brought an issue to light — namely, that I cannot alter any of the variable in the class to be anything but `static`.  And this brings me to my question: **Why on earth can I not edit the variables in that class to not be static?  Why does removing `static` break it?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Private static variables in php class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634712/private-static-variables-in-php-class)

Comment: @JGrice, I do not see how that even comes close to being a duplicate.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `static` and non-static properties...?

Comment: Yes, @deceze, I have read enough to believe that my understanding is sufficient. However, I have read nothing that would indicate that declaring something `static` would be absolutely necessary.

Comment: Certainly not necessary. But if you simply remove the `static` keyword **without also changing the `self::$...` code in which the properties are accessed**, it'll obviously break. You'll have to be a bit more specific about what exactly you're doing and how exactly it breaks.

Comment: BTW, you better regenerate your access keys. Never post **secret** keys on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"static" exists in the scope of the class. Non-static exists in the scope of the object (instance of the class). If you just remove "static" from the existing class, all references to it such as `self::referenceId` will be broken. You would need to replace all of them with `$this->referenceId`. You do understand that 'self' refers to the class and 'this' refers to the object?

Comment: Thank you. I suppose I should have known that, but I did not.  I thought `self::` was fine.